# Image appears blurry in HTML email signature, even when HTML directly opened in Chrome

Tags: html, image, email, cross-browser, html-email

The image itself is not blurry when accessed directly where it's hosted. The HTML email signature makes it appear blurry in Chrome, even when opened directly in Chrome (not through an email client). This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style>table{padding:0px;}td{padding-right:5px;}p{font-family:Arial;color:#002956;font-size:14px;margin:0;}a{text-decoration:none;color:#002956;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr>
    <td width="226" align="center" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 16px; border-right: 1px solid #cdcdcd;">
        <a href="https://www.jccgci.org/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.jccgci.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/JCCGCI_logo_email.png" width="226" height="auto"></a>
    </td>
    <td width="300" style="padding-left: 16px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
        <p style="margin:0; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; color:#002956;"><b style="text-transform: uppercase; font-family:Arial;">Name</b><br />
          Job Title<br />
          Department<br /><br />
          <a style="font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; color: #002956 !important; text-decoration: none !important;" href="tel:7184495000,1234"><b style="color: #00aae7">T:</b> (718) 449-5000 x 1234</a><br />
          <a style="font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; color: #002956 !important; text-decoration: none !important;" href="fax:3479623683"><b style="color: #00aae7">F:</b> (347) 962-3683</a><br />
          <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/Jewish+Community+Council+of+Greater+Coney+Island,+Inc/@40.572754,-74.0043667,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c245c3a27e574d:0x104ef0508520982a!8m2!3d40.5727499!4d-74.0021727" target="_blank">3001 West 37th Street<br />
          Brooklyn, NY 11224</a><br /><br />
          <a style="font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; color: #002956 !important; text-decoration: none !important;" href="https://www.jccgci.org/" target="_blank"><b style="color: #00aae7">JCCGCI.ORG</b></a><br />
          <span style="font-family:Arial; font-size: 12px;"><a href="https://www.nphd.org/" target="_blank"><b>nphd.org&nbsp;</b></a>  |  <a href="http://connect2ny.org/" target="_blank"><b>connect2ny.org&nbsp;</b></a>  |  <a href="http://friendlyvisitingny.org/" target="_blank"><b>friendlyvisitingny.org&nbsp;</b></a></span>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I couldn't replicate the problem in any of my browsers but I tried adding:

```
image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          /* Firefox             */
image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            /* Opera               */
image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Chrome (and Safari) */
```

And that actually caused the image to appear jagged in Firefox and Safari, so I took it out. Any ideas as to why https://www.jccgci.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/JCCGCI_logo_email.png is showing up blurry in Chrome when the HTML email signature is viewed, but not when the image is accessed directly? I'm stumped, especially since I can't replicate it. Does anyone see the image as blurry when opening the above HTML?

Comment: I looked at your email in Chrome Mac and saw no issues. I looked at it in Firefox, no issues. I checked it in Litmus and noticed it doesn't stack in mobile browsers like iPhone 6. Other than mobile stacking, you look good.

Comment: Thanks! When you say doesn't stack, how so? Does it actually get cut off? I checked from iPhone 10 Gmail and the stacking looks alright.

Comment: When I looked at the email in Litmus, the logo displayed most of the width of the content area. It would look better if the logo would stack on top of the rest of the information on the right and become a new row. It would be easier to read. You would have to create a `@media` query in your style sheet to make that happen.

Comment: Try JPEG or GIF rather than png. PNG has a weird resizing at times in Chrome. Since its transparent, try GIF.